# Allow Resize of Window in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I would like to open a window using `window.open` and allow it to be resized under the user's control on IE11.

I have a window that is opened with this javascript:

```
window.open('Welcome.aspx?aid=' + AppId, 'AppId','scrollbars=1,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,status=yes');
```

After opening the window can be resized on Chrome.

It can not be resized on IE11.

The history of this code is that previously we did not want it to resize, but now we want it to resize so we recently added the `resizable=yes`.  We cleared cache so it is not a caching issue.

My question is:

1) What else can I search for in the code to find what might be keeping the page from being resized?

2) What can I do to debug this (perhaps in the f12 window)?

[EDIT] The window.open() javascript will open a window that is resizable if used alone.  So there much be something else in my code that is keeping it from being resizable.  But I don't know how to find it.  I search the source for "resiz" and did not find anything suspicious.  This code is not my code and it is a complete mess so tearing into the code is not my first choice on debugging this.  But if I don't get a good clue from SO in the next 12 hours we will start doing that.

Comment: Does the child window inherit the settings from the parent window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that the **parent** window was opened with this code:

```
'location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resize=yes,status=yes'
```

We change to:

```
'scrollbars=1,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,status=yes'
```

It seems the scrollbar property is carried thru to child windows even if specified on subsequent calls to `window.open()`.

We missed that because it was opened from a different application.  In hindsight it is obvious that we should have checked it, but I don't think the parent window settings should affect child window settings.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I try to check your code and found that you are trying to open .aspx page. So it looks like you are developing an ASP.NET web application.

I tried to create one and made a test with your code in IE 11 browser.

Testing result:

[image]

Based on my testing result, you can see that your JS code is working fine and in IE 11 browser new window is re-sizable.

For testing purpose, you can try to create a new sample project and try to run your above code using that project and check whether IE 11 allows you to resize the window or not.

If it allows you to resize the windows then may be there is something else in your project which is preventing IE 11 to create re-sizable window.

If issue persist then I suggest you to try to test the same code on any other machine to check and verify that whether this is any machine specific issue or not.

If it is machine specific issue then you can try to reset your IE 11 browser with default settings and again try to make a test.

If none of the above suggestions work then let us know about it. We can try to discuss further for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.  Maybe try uninstalling IE and reinstalling it.  Since it worked for chrome, not sure why it wouldn't work for both.  But then I found this...

[Unable to Resize Pop-up Window in IE 11 When Clicking the "Edit" Button in An Embedded View](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/unable-to-resize-pop-up-window-in-ie-11-when-clicking-the-edit-button-in-an-embedded-view)

and

[Pop-Resize Unavailable?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/pop-resize-unavailable/faa0351a-821a-4810-b35f-e91314d0c926?auth=1)